# Pie Chart in Report Builder is divided in lots pieces?

Tags: sql, oracle, oraclereports

My Query creates lots of entries because there are a lot of entries for dates in the view, and when I try to filter out the information in report builder it doesn't divide the pie graph into four pieces but divides it into the number of date entries in the view.

What I am supposed to do is get number parts sold for each class between dates. The dates are to be selected in report builder.

```
SQL Developer Query:
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW QUERY3 AS
SELECT partclass, COUNT(p.partno) AS "Parts Sold", orderdate
  FROM part p, salesorder s, orderprod o
WHERE p.partno = o.partno
  AND o.orderno = s.orderno
GROUP BY partclass, orderdate;

Report Builder Query
SELECT * FROM QUERY3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post a query you use in Reports Builder. Apparently, you'll need to include a `WHERE` clause which restricts the result set by dates. Something like this:

```
select partclass, "Parts Sold", orderdate
from query3
where orderdate between :par_date_from and :par_date_to;  --> this
```

A side note: consider recreating the view and naming the "Parts Sold" column differently, such as `parts_sold`. The way you put it, you'll *always* have to reference that column using double quotes and paying attention to mixed case.

`:par_date_from` and `:par_date_to` represent references to **parameters** you should create in the report. If you use the built-in Parameter Form, you'll be prompted to enter those values. Or, if you run the report differently, you'll have to pass those values to the report in order to use them.

Comment: So I tried your query in report builder and it gives me a prompt to define query parameters. Options under parameter values are only blank and null. I have already defined the parameters in the forms.

Comment: Yes; when you use parameters in query, Reports creates them itself (if they don't exist). Now modify their datatype (to DATE?) and pass values from a form.

Comment: ok, now I am receiving an error when I try to generate a report. It says      "The report parameter ‘StartDate’ has a DefaultValue or a ValidValue that depends on the report parameter “StartDate”. Forward dependencies are not valid." I didn't set default values only available values

Comment: Don't set *any* values for those parameters. They should be passed from a form.